# How to calculate RMS of a sampled analog signal

Tags: discrete-signals, fourier-transform, frequency-spectrum

Consider the below given discrete signal which has been gathered via sampling of an analog current waveform with sampling period $T_s=100\,\mu s$.
I would like to evaluate the RMS value of its first order harmonic which has the frequency $f=58\,Hz$.

[image]

This task can be basically divided into two subtasks:

1. Finding the first order harmonic
2. Evaluating the RMS value

My question is whether I can use the below given formulas for finding the phasor of the first order harmonic ($N=f_s/f$):

$$A_1 = \sum_{k=0}^{N-1} i(k)\cdot \cos\left(\frac{2\pi}{N}\cdot k\right)$$
$$B_1 = -\sum_{k=0}^{N-1} i(k)\cdot \sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{N}\cdot k\right)$$
$$I_1 = \sqrt{A_1^2 + B_1^2}$$
$$\phi_1 = \arctan\left(\frac{B_1}{A_1}\right)$$

My doubts arises from the fact that in my situation $N=\frac{f_s}{f} = \frac{10^4}{58} \approx 172.4$

I have used the below given Scilab code for calculation of the $A_1$ and $B_1$
(supposing that the samples of the current are stored in the vector i_u)

```
N = 4096;
T = 1/58;
Ts = 0.0001;
M = round(T/Ts);
A1 = 0;
B1 = 0;
for k = 1:N
    A1 =   A1 + i_u(k)*cos(2*%pi/M*(k-1));
    B1 = -(B1 + i_u(k)*sin(2*%pi/M*(k-1)));
end
```

This piece of my code calculated following values: $A_1 = - 85287.936$ and $B_1 = - 67.218679$ which don't make sense for me.

Comment: You don't care about the phase, so I'm not sure why you're calculating a phasor; your $I_1$ seems to be proportional to what you're looking for, an RMS.

Comment: Anyway, why does your N cause you any doubts?

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for your reaction. I have just added the source of my doubts to my question.

Comment: These values are just that - values. Why do you think they make no sense? You've really not explained why you think your N is incorrect.

Comment: r.m.s. is:  $$ \sqrt{\frac{1}{N} \sum\limits_{n=0}^{N-1} x^2[n]}  $$  Make sure $N$ is big enough.

Comment: @MarcusMüller as far as the doubts about correctnes of the values of the$A_1$ and $B_1$. The reason is that they provide too high amplitude of the first order harmonic of the current. As far as the doubts about the $N$ I thought that it should be an integer number. In my situation it isn't integer number - I have rounded the $N$ to be an integer number.

Comment: Ok, so you're conflating two things then: of course you're right, a maximum index for summation needs to be an integer. But the way your N is important is that it's the relative frequency of your tone. And that doesn't have to be an integer, or identical to the number of summands.

Comment: @MarcusMüller thank you for clarification regarding the $N$ value. I still have doubts regarding the calculated values of the $A_1$ and $B_1$. Do you have any idea why they provide higher amplitude then the amplitude of the original signal is?

Comment: well, yes! It's right there in your formula: you coherently add up $N$ samples, so that's to be expected.

Comment: I am very sorry but I don't understand how is it possible to have first order harmonic with higher amplitude than the original signal.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson thank you for your reaction. My intention was to calculate the rms of the first order harmonic. Do you think that I can use the your suggested formula also for that case?

Comment: well, if you find a way to ***separate*** the first harmonic (this is the same as the "fundamental", right?) then you can apply the above formula to get the r.m.s.  So then, perhaps the question becomes *"How does one separate a single harmonic from a more broadbanded signal?"*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, if you examine your plot carefully, there are 10 of the apparent periods in the time interval of 0.0172 seconds.  But that really is two cycles of the apparent periodic function and the fundamental frequency is really about 116.3 Hz, and the **5th** harmonic is about 581.4 Hz. The 5th harmonic is very very strong in relationship to the other harmonics.

Now you *could* call the 581.4 Hz your fundamental, but then the 116.3 Hz, which **is** present in your signal, is a *sub-harmonic*.  But I'm gonna call it the fundamental and say there are no subharmonics and that your 581.4 Hz signal is the 5th harmonic.

So one entire period is 8.6 ms or 86 samples.  Or you could get two entire periods of 17.2 ms or 172 samples.

Enter those two periods of data into an FFT of exactly $N$=172.  Every odd-numbered bin should have very low energy, but every bin with an index that is a multiple of 10 should be pretty strong.  The amplitude of that 5th harmonic is in the 10th FFT bin.

Answer (score 0):

The RMS power of a cyclic signal is the RMS power of **1 CYCLE ONLY**.

When calculating signals power we have to do our best to avoid mixing **finite energy signals** with **periodic energy signals**.

Sometimes it happens, mistaking a single pulse for something periodic, or missing a periodic signal as if once-only.

But then power measurements are rendered useless or misleading.

So before measuring signal power you need to calculate `T` the period of the signal first.

In the question you mention you know f1=58Hz but in general it's safer to extract the time period or cycle `T` from the signal directly.

That some one apparently reliable told you **f1=58Hz** ? good.

And the manual reads **f1=58Hz** ? better.

But ultimately the signal is the one you have to pay attention  first, because **it's the signal you are measuring**, not others' statments or something printed on a manual that probably reached your computer through the internet.

So

**1.- in time :**

- take many cycles and cut them between adjacent peaks
- overlap all these cycles
- average them

measure RMS power as told above on this single cycle.

As mentioned in another answer, the more cycles you take the better.

**But run the RMS calculation along** `[t1:dt:t1+T]` **only**

**2.- In frequency :**

- you apply a window around the carrier measure power on the peak
  regardless of it's exactly 58Hz

Would you like a MATLAB script to show all above explained?

Just let me know and will add it to this answer.